# Saving pickle object at each iteration without writing whole object each time

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to save a dictionary as a pickle object.

My dictionary gets bigger and bigger at each iteration in a long for loop, could I save it at each iteration in an efficient manner, such that I only save the additional key:value pair at each iteration instead of re-saving the whole dictionary?

Example:

```
import pickle 

keys = [123,11,2,5]
values = [[10,3,2,1],[0],[1],[2,3],[3]]

for i in range(0,4):
    mydict[keys[i]] = values[i]
pickle.dump(mydict, open('/mydir/mydict.p','w'))
```

As one can see here I save mydict at the end of the loop, but ideally I'd save it at each part of the for loop in an efficient manner.

Comment: I suggest you use the [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) module instead of a regular dictionary. This will provide you with "persistent, dictionary-like objects" that can be synced to the backing-file whenever desired. The keys used can only be strings, but that's usually not hard to manage.

Comment: with a regular dict you will still have to load it to update it.

Comment: What is your actual use case? We may be able to suggest a more efficient solution if you tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @merlin2011 I am scraping websites and at each for loop I save an entire list into a given key of the python dictionary.  There may be better ways to do it and I'd be open to suggestions but I thought a dynamic dictionary that I save at each iteration was a good way to go.

Comment: Consider using a sqlite database and just inserting one record for each element in the list. This would achieve the effect of writing to disk incrementally, as well as making your data more cross-platform and cross-language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for something that saves large dictionaries of data to disk or to a database, and can utilize pickling and encoding (codecs and hashmaps), then you might want to look at `klepto`.

`klepto` provides a dictionary abstraction for writing to a database, including treating your filesystem as a database (i.e. writing the entire dictionary to a single file, or writing each entry to it's own file).  For large data, I often choose to represent the dictionary as a directory on my filesystem, and have each entry be a file.  `klepto` also offers caching algorithms, so if you are using a filesystem backend for the dictionary you can avoid some speed penalty by utilizing memory caching.

```
>>> from klepto.archives import dir_archive
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':map, 'd':None}
>>> # map a dict to a filesystem directory
>>> demo = dir_archive('demo', d, serialized=True) 
>>> demo['a']
1
>>> demo['c']
<built-in function map>
>>> demo          
dir_archive('demo', {'a': 1, 'c': <built-in function map>, 'b': 2, 'd': None}, cached=True)
>>> # is set to cache to memory, so use 'dump' to dump to the filesystem 
>>> demo.dump()
>>> del demo
>>> 
>>> demo = dir_archive('demo', {}, serialized=True)
>>> demo
dir_archive('demo', {}, cached=True)
>>> # demo is empty, load from disk
>>> demo.load()
>>> demo
dir_archive('demo', {'a': 1, 'c': <built-in function map>, 'b': 2, 'd': None}, cached=True)
>>> demo['c']
<built-in function map>
>>>
```

`klepto` also has other flags such as `compression` and `memmode` that can be used to customize how your data is stored (e.g. compression level, memory map mode, etc).
It's equally easy (the same exact interface) to use a (MySQL, etc) database as a backend instead of your filesystem.  You can also turn off memory caching, so every read/write goes directly to the archive, simply by setting `cached=False`.

`klepto` provides access to customizing your encoding, by building a custom `keymap`.

```
>>> from klepto.keymaps import *
>>> 
>>> s = stringmap(encoding='hex_codec')
>>> x = [1,2,'3',min]
>>> s(x)
'285b312c20322c202733272c203c6275696c742d696e2066756e6374696f6e206d696e3e5d2c29'
>>> p = picklemap(serializer='dill')
>>> p(x)
'\x80\x02]q\x00(K\x01K\x02U\x013q\x01c__builtin__\nmin\nq\x02e\x85q\x03.'
>>> sp = s+p
>>> sp(x)
'\x80\x02UT28285b312c20322c202733272c203c6275696c742d696e2066756e6374696f6e206d696e3e5d2c292c29q\x00.'
```

`klepto` also provides a lot of caching algorithms (like `mru`, `lru`, `lfu`, etc), to help you manage your in-memory cache, and will use the algorithm do the dump and load to the archive backend for you.

You can use the flag `cached=False` to turn off memory caching completely, and directly read and write to and from disk or database. If your entries are large enough, you might pick to write to disk, where you put each entry in it's own file.  Here's an example that does both.

```
>>> from klepto.archives import dir_archive
>>> # does not hold entries in memory, each entry will be stored on disk
>>> demo = dir_archive('demo', {}, serialized=True, cached=False)
>>> demo['a'] = 10
>>> demo['b'] = 20
>>> demo['c'] = min
>>> demo['d'] = [1,2,3]
```

However that usually slows execution down a bit… it's usually better to specify the maximum amount to hold in memory cache and pick a good caching algorithm.

Get `klepto` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation